# Strange windows networking error code

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, authentication, wpa2-psk, error-logging

I am able to connect to an access point with linux (android), and even windows on my laptop.  However, my desktop doesn't want to connect to the router.  I get the error code 0x8e5e442 in the windows network troubleshooter (the default troubleshooter that comes with the Win7 Ult 64os).  I tried googling this code but nothing comes up.  Has anyone seen this before or have a resource to look up this code?  I was unable to find any databases for these codes.

Comment: is this the correct code? I think you miss number.

Comment: This is the correct code.

Comment: that are only 7 numbers. Errorcodes has 8. That why I ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although i solved this months ago, ill go ahead and answer this.

Somehow installing some software changed my network setting to use a static IP without me knowing.  Had i run ip config immediately i would have noticed this error.